# I can't update ubuntu 10.04 to 12.04 / 14.04

Tags: 14.04, upgrade, updates, 10.04

I'm trying to update an old server that runs Ubuntu 10.04 but I can't. I'm trying from terminal because update center tells me that "my Ubuntu release is not supported anymore" and I can't do anything in this windows because it's freezed.

I did that in the terminal:

```
sudo do-release-upgrade -d
```

And this is the message that I got:

```
Comprobando el gestor de paquetes
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree        
Reading state information... Done
Building data structures... Done 
WARNING: Failed to read mirror file

.....

Ign http://old-releases.ubuntu.com lucid/restricted TranslationIndex                                                                                        
Ign http://old-releases.ubuntu.com lucid/universe TranslationIndex                                                                                          
Err http://old-releases.ubuntu.com lucid/main Translation-en                                                                                                

Hit http://old-releases.ubuntu.com lucid/main Translation-es                                                                                                
Err http://old-releases.ubuntu.com lucid/multiverse Translation-en                                                                                          

Hit http://old-releases.ubuntu.com lucid/multiverse Translation-es                                                                                          
Err http://old-releases.ubuntu.com lucid/restricted Translation-en                                                                                          

Hit http://old-releases.ubuntu.com lucid/restricted Translation-es                                                                                          
Err http://old-releases.ubuntu.com lucid/universe Translation-en                                                                                            

Hit http://old-releases.ubuntu.com lucid/universe Translation-es                                                                                            
Err http://old-releases.ubuntu.com lucid/main Translation-en                                                                                                

Err http://old-releases.ubuntu.com lucid/multiverse Translation-en                                                                                          

Err http://old-releases.ubuntu.com lucid/restricted Translation-en                                                                                          

Err http://old-releases.ubuntu.com lucid/universe Translation-en   

.....

E:Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
```

I've googled the last error ([Update Manager doesn't allow me to upgrade from version 10.10 to 12.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/239258/update-manager-doesnt-allow-me-to-upgrade-from-version-10-10-to-12-10)) and I've checked this files: **cat /var/log/dist-upgrade/apt.log | grep Broken**

```
Broken libc6:i386 Conflicts on libc6-i686 [ i386 ] < 2.11.1-0ubuntu7.21 > ( libs )
Broken libc6:i386 Breaks on liblouis0 [ i386 ] < 1.7.0-2 > ( libs ) (< 2.3.0-2)
Broken libpolkit-gobject-1-0:i386 Breaks on libpolkit-gtk-1-0 [ i386 ] < 0.96-2ubuntu2 > ( libs ) (< 0.99)
Broken ure:i386 Breaks on openoffice.org-core [ i386 ] < 1:3.2.0-7ubuntu4.4 > ( editors ) (< 1:3.3~)
Broken xserver-xorg-core:i386 Breaks on xserver-xorg-video-6 [ i386 ] < none > ( none )
Broken libnspr4-0d:i386 Conflicts on libnspr4 [ i386 ] < none -> 4.8.9-1ubuntu2 > ( libs ) (< 2:4)
Broken gnome-settings-daemon:i386 Depends on libnss3 [ i386 ] < none -> 3.13.1.with.ckbi.1.88-1ubuntu6 > ( libs ) (>= 3.12.0~1.9b1)
Broken libreoffice-core:i386 Depends on libnss3 [ i386 ] < none -> 3.13.1.with.ckbi.1.88-1ubuntu6 > ( libs ) (>= 3.12.0~1.9b1)
Broken libnm-util2:i386 Depends on libnss3 [ i386 ] < none -> 3.13.1.with.ckbi.1.88-1ubuntu6 > ( libs ) (>= 3.12.0~1.9b1)
Broken xz-lzma:i386 Conflicts on lzma [ i386 ] < 4.43-14ubuntu2 -> 9.22-2ubuntu1 > ( utils )
Broken gnome-control-center:i386 Depends on libnm-util2 [ i386 ] < none -> 0.9.4.0-0ubuntu3 > ( libs ) (>= 0.8.998)
Broken gvfs-libs:i386 Conflicts on libgvfscommon0 [ i386 ] < 1.6.1-0ubuntu1build1 > ( libs )
Broken libnm-glib4:i386 Depends on libnm-util2 [ i386 ] < none -> 0.9.4.0-0ubuntu3 > ( libs ) (>= 0.9.3.995+git201203081848.bba834f)
Broken libcamel-1.2-29:i386 Depends on libnss3 [ i386 ] < none -> 3.13.1.with.ckbi.1.88-1ubuntu6 > ( libs ) (>= 3.12.0~beta3)
Broken gnome-control-center-data:i386 Conflicts on capplets-data [ i386 ] < 1:2.30.1-0ubuntu2 > ( gnome )
Broken gnome-control-center-data:i386 Breaks on gnome-settings-daemon [ i386 ] < 2.30.1-0ubuntu1.1 -> 3.4.1-0ubuntu1 > ( gnome ) (< 3.0)
Broken console-setup:i386 Conflicts on console-terminus [ i386 ] < 4.30-2 > ( fonts )
Broken libdrm-nouveau1a:i386 Conflicts on libdrm-nouveau1 [ i386 ] < 2.4.18-1ubuntu3 > ( libs )
Broken libnss3-1d:i386 Depends on libnspr4-0d [ i386 ] < 4.10.7-0ubuntu0.10.04.1 > ( universe/libs ) (>= 4.8.6)
Broken libedataserver1.2-11:i386 Depends on libnspr4-0d [ i386 ] < 4.10.7-0ubuntu0.10.04.1 > ( universe/libs ) (>= 4.7.3-0ubuntu1~)
Broken foomatic-db-compressed-ppds:i386 Conflicts on foomatic-db [ i386 ] < 20100216-0ubuntu3 -> 20120322-0ubuntu1 > ( text )
Broken foomatic-db-compressed-ppds:i386 Conflicts on foomatic-db-hpijs [ i386 ] < none > ( none )
Broken foomatic-db-compressed-ppds:i386 Breaks on foomatic-db [ i386 ] < 20100216-0ubuntu3 -> 20120322-0ubuntu1 > ( text )
Broken libebook-1.2-12:i386 Depends on libcamel-1.2-29 [ i386 ] < none -> 3.2.3-0ubuntu6 > ( libs ) (>= 3.2)
Broken libnm-gtk0:i386 Depends on libnm-glib4 [ i386 ] < none -> 0.9.4.0-0ubuntu3 > ( libs ) (>= 0.8.998)
Broken indicator-messages:i386 Conflicts on indicator-me [ i386 ] < 0.2.6-0ubuntu1 > ( gnome )
Broken pm-utils:i386 Conflicts on pm-utils-powersave-policy [ i386 ] < 0.3.1 > ( admin )
Broken ntfs-3g:i386 Conflicts on libntfs-3g75 [ i386 ] < 1:2010.3.6-1ubuntu1 > ( libs )
Broken gnome-session:i386 Depends on gnome-settings-daemon [ i386 ] < 2.30.1-0ubuntu1.1 -> 3.4.1-0ubuntu1 > ( gnome ) (>= 3.0)
Broken libnm-glib-vpn1:i386 Depends on libnm-util2 [ i386 ] < none -> 0.9.4.0-0ubuntu3 > ( libs ) (>= 0.7.0)
Broken evolution-data-server:i386 Depends on libcamel-1.2-29 [ i386 ] < none -> 3.2.3-0ubuntu6 > ( libs ) (= 3.2.3-0ubuntu6)
Broken libreoffice-emailmerge:i386 Depends on libreoffice-core [ i386 ] < none -> 1:3.5.2-2ubuntu1 > ( editors )
Broken libreoffice-writer:i386 Depends on libreoffice-core [ i386 ] < none -> 1:3.5.2-2ubuntu1 > ( editors ) (= 1:3.5.2-2ubuntu1)
Broken libreoffice-base-core:i386 Depends on libreoffice-core [ i386 ] < none -> 1:3.5.2-2ubuntu1 > ( editors ) (= 1:3.5.2-2ubuntu1)
Broken libreoffice-math:i386 Depends on libreoffice-core [ i386 ] < none -> 1:3.5.2-2ubuntu1 > ( editors ) (= 1:3.5.2-2ubuntu1)
Broken network-manager-pptp:i386 Depends on libnm-glib-vpn1 [ i386 ] < none -> 0.9.4.0-0ubuntu3 > ( libs ) (>= 0.7.999)
Broken libedataserverui-3.0-1:i386 Depends on libcamel-1.2-29 [ i386 ] < none -> 3.2.3-0ubuntu6 > ( libs ) (>= 3.2)
Broken gnome-panel:i386 Depends on libedataserverui-3.0-1 [ i386 ] < none -> 3.2.3-0ubuntu6 > ( libs ) (>= 3.2.3)
Broken liboauth0:i386 Depends on libnss3 [ i386 ] < none -> 3.13.1.with.ckbi.1.88-1ubuntu6 > ( libs ) (>= 3.12.0~1.9b1)
Broken gnome-media:i386 Breaks on gnome-control-center [ i386 ] < 1:2.30.1-0ubuntu2 -> 1:3.4.1-0ubuntu1 > ( gnome ) (< 1:3.0)
Broken network-manager-pptp-gnome:i386 Depends on libnm-glib-vpn1 [ i386 ] < none -> 0.9.4.0-0ubuntu3 > ( libs ) (>= 0.8.998)
Broken network-manager:i386 Depends on libnm-glib4 [ i386 ] < none -> 0.9.4.0-0ubuntu3 > ( libs ) (>= 0.9.4.0~git201203162258.69247a0)
Broken libcamel1.2-14:i386 Depends on libedataserver1.2-11 [ i386 ] < 2.28.3.1-0ubuntu6.1 > ( libs ) (>= 2.28.3.1)
Broken libgdata13:i386 Depends on liboauth0 [ i386 ] < none -> 0.9.4-3 > ( libs ) (>= 0.9.1)
Broken indicator-datetime:i386 Depends on libedataserverui-3.0-1 [ i386 ] < none -> 3.2.3-0ubuntu6 > ( libs ) (>= 3.2.3)
Broken libc6-dev:i386 Breaks on gcj-4.4-base [ i386 ] < 4.4.3-1ubuntu4.1 > ( libs ) (< 4.4.6-2ubuntu2)
Broken gnome-applets:i386 Depends on gnome-panel [ i386 ] < 1:2.30.2-0ubuntu0.2 -> 1:3.4.1-0ubuntu1 > ( universe/gnome ) (>= 2.91.91)
Broken totem-plugins:i386 Depends on libgdata13 [ i386 ] < none -> 0.12.0-1 > ( libs ) (>= 0.8.1)
Broken ubuntuone-client-gnome:i386 Depends on libebook-1.2-12 [ i386 ] < none -> 3.2.3-0ubuntu6 > ( libs ) (>= 3.2.3)
Broken network-manager-gnome:i386 Depends on libnm-glib-vpn1 [ i386 ] < none -> 0.9.4.0-0ubuntu3 > ( libs ) (>= 0.7.999)
Broken odbcinst1debian2:i386 Conflicts on odbcinst1debian1 [ i386 ] < 2.2.11-21 > ( libs )
Broken python-uno:i386 Depends on libreoffice-core [ i386 ] < none -> 1:3.5.2-2ubuntu1 > ( editors ) (= 1:3.5.2-2ubuntu1)
Broken gnome-session-fallback:i386 Depends on gnome-settings-daemon [ i386 ] < 2.30.1-0ubuntu1.1 -> 3.4.1-0ubuntu1 > ( gnome ) (>= 3.0)
Broken gnome-power-manager:i386 Depends on gnome-settings-daemon [ i386 ] < 2.30.1-0ubuntu1.1 -> 3.4.1-0ubuntu1 > ( gnome ) (>= 3.2)
Broken libept0:i386 Depends on libapt-pkg-libc6.10-6-4.8 [ i386 ] < none > ( none )
Broken sessioninstaller:i386 Conflicts on gnome-codec-install [ i386 ] < 0.4.2ubuntu2 -> 0.4.7+nmu1ubuntu3 > ( universe/gnome )
Broken libedata-book-1.2-11:i386 Depends on libebook-1.2-12 [ i386 ] < none -> 3.2.3-0ubuntu6 > ( libs ) (>= 3.2.3)
Broken libebook1.2-9:i386 Depends on libcamel1.2-14 [ i386 ] < 2.28.3.1-0ubuntu6.1 > ( libs ) (>= 2.27)
Broken gstreamer0.10-nice:i386 Breaks on libgstfarsight0.10-0 [ i386 ] < 0.0.17-2ubuntu2 > ( libs ) (< 0.0.23)
Broken indicator-appmenu:i386 Conflicts on libdbusmenu-glib1 [ i386 ] < 0.2.9-0ubuntu3.1 > ( libs ) (< 0.3.7)
Broken nvidia-common:i386 Conflicts on nvidia-current-modaliases [ i386 ] < 195.36.24-0ubuntu1~10.04.3 > ( admin )
Broken libebackend1.2-0:i386 Depends on libedataserver1.2-11 [ i386 ] < 2.28.3.1-0ubuntu6.1 > ( libs ) (>= 2.28.3.1)
Broken libsdl1.2debian:i386 Conflicts on libsdl1.2debian-pulseaudio [ i386 ] < 1.2.14-4ubuntu1.1 > ( libs )
Broken python-gnome2:i386 Conflicts on python-gnomecanvas [ i386 ] < 2.28.0-1ubuntu1 > ( python )
Broken libfolks-eds25:i386 Depends on libebook-1.2-12 [ i386 ] < none -> 3.2.3-0ubuntu6 > ( libs ) (>= 3.2.3)
Broken libcdt4:i386 Conflicts on libgraphviz4 [ i386 ] < 2.20.2-8ubuntu3.2 > ( libs )
Broken libreoffice-draw:i386 Depends on libreoffice-core [ i386 ] < none -> 1:3.5.2-2ubuntu1 > ( editors ) (= 1:3.5.2-2ubuntu1)
Broken libmtp-common:i386 Breaks on libmtp8 [ i386 ] < 1.0.2-1ubuntu1 > ( libs ) (<= 1.0.6-6)
Broken gdm:i386 Breaks on gdm-guest-session [ i386 ] < 0.15ubuntu0.1 > ( gnome )
Broken geoclue-ubuntu-geoip:i386 Depends on libnm-glib4 [ i386 ] < none -> 0.9.4.0-0ubuntu3 > ( libs ) (>= 0.7.999)
Broken libcurl3-nss:i386 Depends on libnss3 [ i386 ] < none -> 3.13.1.with.ckbi.1.88-1ubuntu6 > ( libs ) (>= 3.12.0~beta2)
Broken libreoffice-gtk:i386 Depends on libreoffice-core [ i386 ] < none -> 1:3.5.2-2ubuntu1 > ( editors ) (= 1:3.5.2-2ubuntu1)
Broken libpurple0:i386 Depends on libnss3 [ i386 ] < none -> 3.13.1.with.ckbi.1.88-1ubuntu6 > ( libs ) (>= 3.12.0~1.9b1)
Broken openoffice.org-writer:i386 Depends on libreoffice-writer [ i386 ] < none -> 1:3.5.2-2ubuntu1 > ( editors )
Broken libreoffice-calc:i386 Depends on libreoffice-core [ i386 ] < none -> 1:3.5.2-2ubuntu1 > ( editors ) (= 1:3.5.2-2ubuntu1)
Broken libreoffice-gnome:i386 Depends on libreoffice-core [ i386 ] < none -> 1:3.5.2-2ubuntu1 > ( editors ) (= 1:3.5.2-2ubuntu1)
Broken libnm-util1:i386 Depends on libnspr4-0d [ i386 ] < 4.10.7-0ubuntu0.10.04.1 > ( universe/libs ) (>= 4.7.3-0ubuntu1~)
Broken chromium-browser:i386 Depends on libnspr4-0d [ i386 ] < 4.10.7-0ubuntu0.10.04.1 > ( universe/libs ) (>= 4.7.3-0ubuntu1~)
Broken libreoffice-help-en-us:i386 Depends on libreoffice-writer [ i386 ] < none -> 1:3.5.2-2ubuntu1 > ( editors )
Broken libreoffice-help-en-us:i386 Depends on language-support-translations-en [ i386 ] < none > ( none )
Broken libubuntuone-1.0-1:i386 Depends on ubuntuone-client-gnome [ i386 ] < 1.2.2-0ubuntu2.3 -> 3.0.0-0ubuntu1 > ( gnome ) (>= 1.1.2)
Broken libecal1.2-7:i386 Depends on libedataserver1.2-11 [ i386 ] < 2.28.3.1-0ubuntu6.1 > ( libs ) (>= 2.28.3.1)
Broken telepathy-mission-control-5:i386 Depends on libnm-glib4 [ i386 ] < none -> 0.9.4.0-0ubuntu3 > ( libs ) (>= 0.7.999)
Broken libreoffice-impress:i386 Depends on libreoffice-core [ i386 ] < none -> 1:3.5.2-2ubuntu1 > ( editors ) (= 1:3.5.2-2ubuntu1)
Broken libfarstream-0.1-0:i386 Depends on gstreamer0.10-nice [ i386 ] < 0.0.10-2build1 -> 0.1.1-2ubuntu1 > ( net ) (>= 0.1.0)
Broken libreoffice-style-tango:i386 Depends on libreoffice-core [ i386 ] < none -> 1:3.5.2-2ubuntu1 > ( editors )
Broken openoffice.org-gnome:i386 Depends on libreoffice-gnome [ i386 ] < none -> 1:3.5.2-2ubuntu1 > ( gnome )
Broken openoffice.org-impress:i386 Depends on libreoffice-impress [ i386 ] < none -> 1:3.5.2-2ubuntu1 > ( editors )
Broken openoffice.org-draw:i386 Depends on libreoffice-draw [ i386 ] < none -> 1:3.5.2-2ubuntu1 > ( editors )
Broken openoffice.org-gtk:i386 Depends on libreoffice-gtk [ i386 ] < none -> 1:3.5.2-2ubuntu1 > ( gnome )
Broken gir1.2-ubuntuoneui-3.0:i386 Breaks on python-ubuntuone [ i386 ] < 0.3.1-0ubuntu1 > ( python )
Broken thunderbird-gnome-support:i386 Depends on libebook-1.2-12 [ i386 ] < none -> 3.2.3-0ubuntu6 > ( libs )
Broken libreoffice-help-es:i386 Depends on libreoffice-writer [ i386 ] < none -> 1:3.5.2-2ubuntu1 > ( editors )
Broken libreoffice-help-es:i386 Depends on language-support-translations-es [ i386 ] < none > ( none )
Broken ubuntu-desktop:i386 Depends on gnome-session [ i386 ] < 2.30.0-0ubuntu1 -> 3.2.1-0ubuntu8 > ( gnome )
Broken gnome-font-viewer:i386 Breaks on capplets-data [ i386 ] < 1:2.30.1-0ubuntu2 > ( gnome ) (< 1:3.0.0)
Broken gnome-font-viewer:i386 Breaks on gnome-control-center [ i386 ] < 1:2.30.1-0ubuntu2 -> 1:3.4.1-0ubuntu1 > ( gnome ) (< 1:3.0.0)
Broken nautilus-sendto-empathy:i386 Depends on libebook-1.2-12 [ i386 ] < none -> 3.2.3-0ubuntu6 > ( libs ) (>= 3.2.3)
Broken gcj-4.4-jre-lib:i386 Depends on gcj-4.4-base [ i386 ] < 4.4.3-1ubuntu4.1 > ( libs ) (>= 4.4.2-9)
Broken libgcj10:i386 Depends on gcj-4.4-base [ i386 ] < 4.4.3-1ubuntu4.1 > ( libs ) (>= 4.4.3-1ubuntu4.1)
Broken libecryptfs0:i386 Depends on libnss3 [ i386 ] < none -> 3.13.1.with.ckbi.1.88-1ubuntu6 > ( libs ) (>= 3.12.0~1.9b1)
Broken libreoffice-help-en-gb:i386 Depends on libreoffice-writer [ i386 ] < none -> 1:3.5.2-2ubuntu1 > ( editors )
Broken libreoffice-help-en-gb:i386 Depends on language-support-translations-en [ i386 ] < none > ( none )
Broken telepathy-haze:i386 Depends on libpurple0 [ i386 ] < 1:2.6.6-1ubuntu4.6 -> 1:2.10.3-0ubuntu1 > ( net ) (>= 1:2.7.0)
Broken libubuntuoneui-3.0-1:i386 Depends on liboauth0 [ i386 ] < none -> 0.9.4-3 > ( libs ) (>= 0.9.1)
Broken openoffice.org-math:i386 Depends on libreoffice-math [ i386 ] < none -> 1:3.5.2-2ubuntu1 > ( editors )
Broken libreoffice-style-human:i386 Depends on libreoffice-core [ i386 ] < none -> 1:3.5.2-2ubuntu1 > ( editors )
Broken gnome-games-data:i386 Breaks on gnome-games-common [ i386 ] < 1:2.30.0-0ubuntu6 > ( games )
Broken telepathy-gabble:i386 Breaks on telepathy-mission-control-5 [ i386 ] < 5.3.2-3 -> 1:5.12.0-0ubuntu2 > ( net ) (< 1:5.5)
Broken openoffice.org-help-es:i386 Depends on libreoffice-help-es [ i386 ] < none -> 1:3.5.2-2ubuntu1 > ( doc )
Broken openoffice.org-help-en-gb:i386 Depends on libreoffice-help-en-gb [ i386 ] < none -> 1:3.5.2-2ubuntu1 > ( doc )
Broken openoffice.org-calc:i386 Depends on libreoffice-calc [ i386 ] < none -> 1:3.5.2-2ubuntu1 > ( editors )
Broken openoffice.org-help-en-us:i386 Depends on libreoffice-help-en-us [ i386 ] < none -> 1:3.5.2-2ubuntu1 > ( doc )
Broken xulrunner-1.9.2:i386 Depends on libnspr4-0d [ i386 ] < 4.10.7-0ubuntu0.10.04.1 > ( universe/libs ) (>= 4.7.3-0ubuntu1~)
Broken libbrasero-media0:i386 Depends on brasero-common [ i386 ] < 2.30.2-0ubuntu1.1 -> 3.4.1-0ubuntu1 > ( gnome ) (< 2.31)
Broken libexchange-storage1.2-3:i386 Depends on libedataserver1.2-11 [ i386 ] < 2.28.3.1-0ubuntu6.1 > ( libs ) (>= 2.28.3.1)
Broken libmagickcore2-extra:i386 Depends on libgraphviz4 [ i386 ] < 2.20.2-8ubuntu3.2 > ( libs ) (>= 2.20.0)
Broken libedata-cal1.2-6:i386 Depends on libebackend1.2-0 [ i386 ] < 2.28.3.1-0ubuntu6.1 > ( libs ) (>= 2.28.3.1)
Broken gnome-about:i386 Depends on gnome-desktop-data [ i386 ] < 1:2.30.2-0ubuntu1 -> 1:2.32.1-0ubuntu9 > ( universe/gnome ) (= 1:2.30.2-0ubuntu1)
Broken python-farsight:i386 Depends on python [ i386 ] < 2.6.5-0ubuntu1.1 -> 2.7.3-0ubuntu2 > ( python ) (< 2.7)
Broken libegroupwise1.2-13:i386 Depends on libedataserver1.2-11 [ i386 ] < 2.28.3.1-0ubuntu6.1 > ( libs ) (>= 2.28.3.1)
Broken libnm-glib2:i386 Depends on libnm-util1 [ i386 ] < 0.8-0ubuntu3.3 > ( libs ) (>= 0.8~a~git.20090804t185522.4bab334)
Broken gnome-user-guide-en:i386 Depends on gnome-user-guide [ i386 ] < 2.30.0+git20100403ubuntu3 -> 3.4.1-1 > ( gnome ) (= 2.30.0+git20100403ubuntu3)
Broken gnome-user-guide-es:i386 Depends on gnome-user-guide [ i386 ] < 2.30.0+git20100403ubuntu3 -> 3.4.1-1 > ( gnome ) (= 2.30.0+git20100403ubuntu3)
Broken openoffice.org-base-core:i386 Depends on openoffice.org-core [ i386 ] < 1:3.2.0-7ubuntu4.4 > ( editors ) (= 1:3.2.0-7ubuntu4.4)
Broken python-gnomeapplet:i386 Depends on python [ i386 ] < 2.6.5-0ubuntu1.1 -> 2.7.3-0ubuntu2 > ( python ) (< 2.7)
Broken libedataserverui1.2-8:i386 Depends on libcamel1.2-14 [ i386 ] < 2.28.3.1-0ubuntu6.1 > ( libs ) (>= 2.27)
Broken libedata-book1.2-2:i386 Depends on libcamel1.2-14 [ i386 ] < 2.28.3.1-0ubuntu6.1 > ( libs ) (>= 2.27)
Broken openoffice.org-emailmerge:i386 Depends on libreoffice-emailmerge [ i386 ] < none -> 1:3.5.2-2ubuntu1 > ( editors )
Broken libperl5.10:i386 Depends on perl-base [ i386 ] < 5.10.1-8ubuntu2.4 -> 5.14.2-6ubuntu2 > ( perl ) (= 5.10.1-8ubuntu2.4)
Broken google-chrome-stable:i386 Depends on libnss3-1d [ i386 ] < 3.17.4-0ubuntu0.10.04.1 > ( libs ) (>= 3.12.3)
Broken unoconv:i386 Depends on python-uno [ i386 ] < 1:3.2.0-7ubuntu4.4 -> 1:3.5.2-2ubuntu1 > ( python )
Broken libpulse-browse0:i386 Depends on libpulse0 [ i386 ] < 1:0.9.22~0.9.21+stable-queue-32-g8478-0ubuntu14 -> 1:1.1-0ubuntu15 > ( libs ) (= 1:0.9.22~0.9.21+stable-queue-32-g8478-0ubuntu14)
Broken esound-clients:i386 Depends on esound-common [ i386 ] < 0.2.41-6ubuntu1 -> 0.2.41-10build3 > ( sound ) (= 0.2.41-6ubuntu1)
Broken libglib2.0-0:i386 Breaks on gnome-control-center [ i386 ] < 1:2.30.1-0ubuntu2 -> 1:3.4.1-0ubuntu1 > ( gnome ) (< 1:3)
Broken ecryptfs-utils:i386 Depends on libecryptfs0 [ i386 ] < none -> 96-0ubuntu3 > ( libs )
Broken ppp:i386 Breaks on network-manager-pptp [ i386 ] < 0.8-0ubuntu3 -> 0.9.4.0-0ubuntu1 > ( net ) (<= 0.8.0.999-1)
Broken gnome-control-center:i386 Depends on libnm-glib4 [ i386 ] < none -> 0.9.4.0-0ubuntu3 > ( libs ) (>= 0.8.998)
Broken libreoffice-common:i386 Depends on libreoffice-style-default [ i386 ] < none > ( none )
Broken libreoffice-common:i386 Depends on libreoffice-style [ i386 ] < none > ( none )
Broken gnome-icon-theme-symbolic:i386 Breaks on gnome-power-manager [ i386 ] < 2.30.0-0ubuntu1.1 -> 3.4.0-0ubuntu1 > ( gnome ) (< 3.2)
Broken indicator-power:i386 Depends on gnome-control-center [ i386 ] < 1:2.30.1-0ubuntu2 -> 1:3.4.1-0ubuntu1 > ( gnome ) (>= 3.1)
Broken network-manager-pptp:i386 Depends on libnm-glib-vpn1 [ i386 ] < none -> 0.9.4.0-0ubuntu3 > ( libs ) (>= 0.7.999)
Broken network-manager-pptp-gnome:i386 Depends on libnm-glib2 [ i386 ] < 0.8-0ubuntu3.3 > ( libs ) (>= 0.8~a~git.20090917t210753.fdb5ef2)
Broken network-manager-pptp-gnome:i386 Depends on libnm-util1 [ i386 ] < 0.8-0ubuntu3.3 > ( libs ) (>= 0.7.1~20090213+gitf142e15)
Broken network-manager-pptp-gnome:i386 Depends on network-manager-pptp [ i386 ] < 0.8-0ubuntu3 -> 0.9.4.0-0ubuntu1 > ( net )
Broken gnome-power-manager:i386 Depends on gnome-settings-daemon [ i386 ] < 2.30.1-0ubuntu1.1 -> 3.4.1-0ubuntu1 > ( gnome ) (>= 3.2)
Broken openoffice.org-common:i386 Depends on libreoffice-common [ i386 ] < none -> 1:3.5.2-2ubuntu1 > ( editors ) (>= 1:3.3.0~rc4-2)
Broken libreoffice-java-common:i386 Depends on libreoffice-common [ i386 ] < none -> 1:3.5.2-2ubuntu1 > ( editors )
Broken chromium-browser-l10n:i386 Depends on chromium-browser [ i386 ] < 25.0.1364.160-0ubuntu0.10.04.1 > ( universe/web ) (= 25.0.1364.160-0ubuntu0.10.04.1)
Broken chromium-codecs-ffmpeg:i386 Depends on chromium-browser [ i386 ] < 25.0.1364.160-0ubuntu0.10.04.1 > ( universe/web ) (>= 4.0.203.0~)
Broken python-papyon:i386 Depends on python-farsight [ i386 ] < 0.0.17-2ubuntu2 > ( python )
Broken openoffice.org-java-common:i386 Depends on libreoffice-java-common [ i386 ] < none -> 1:3.5.2-2ubuntu1 > ( editors )
Broken gir1.2-ubuntuoneui-3.0:i386 Depends on libubuntuoneui-3.0-1 [ i386 ] < none -> 3.0.0-0ubuntu1 > ( libs ) (>= 2.99.3)
Broken rhythmbox-ubuntuone:i386 Depends on gir1.2-ubuntuoneui-3.0 [ i386 ] < none -> 3.0.0-0ubuntu1 > ( introspection ) (>= 3.0.0)
Broken python-farsight:i386 Depends on python [ i386 ] < 2.6.5-0ubuntu1.1 -> 2.7.3-0ubuntu2 > ( python ) (< 2.7)
Broken gnome-icon-theme-symbolic:i386 Breaks on gnome-power-manager [ i386 ] < 2.30.0-0ubuntu1.1 -> 3.4.0-0ubuntu1 > ( gnome ) (< 3.2)
Broken gnome-power-manager:i386 Depends on gnome-settings-daemon [ i386 ] < 2.30.1-0ubuntu1.1 -> 3.4.1-0ubuntu1 > ( gnome ) (>= 3.2)
Broken unity-scope-musicstores:i386 Depends on rhythmbox-ubuntuone [ i386 ] < none -> 3.0.0-0ubuntu1 > ( gnome )
Broken python-papyon:i386 Depends on python-farsight [ i386 ] < 0.0.17-2ubuntu2 > ( python )
Broken python-farsight:i386 Depends on python [ i386 ] < 2.6.5-0ubuntu1.1 -> 2.7.3-0ubuntu2 > ( python ) (< 2.7)
Broken gnome-icon-theme-symbolic:i386 Breaks on gnome-power-manager [ i386 ] < 2.30.0-0ubuntu1.1 -> 3.4.0-0ubuntu1 > ( gnome ) (< 3.2)
Broken gnome-power-manager:i386 Depends on gnome-settings-daemon [ i386 ] < 2.30.1-0ubuntu1.1 -> 3.4.1-0ubuntu1 > ( gnome ) (>= 3.2)
Broken python-papyon:i386 Depends on python-farsight [ i386 ] < 0.0.17-2ubuntu2 > ( python )
Broken telepathy-butterfly:i386 Depends on python-papyon [ i386 ] < 0.4.8-0ubuntu2.1 > ( python ) (>= 0.4.2)
Broken gnome-icon-theme-symbolic:i386 Breaks on gnome-power-manager [ i386 ] < 2.30.0-0ubuntu1.1 -> 3.4.0-0ubuntu1 > ( gnome ) (< 3.2)
Broken gnome-power-manager:i386 Depends on gnome-settings-daemon [ i386 ] < 2.30.1-0ubuntu1.1 -> 3.4.1-0ubuntu1 > ( gnome ) (>= 3.2)
Broken gnome-icon-theme-symbolic:i386 Breaks on gnome-power-manager [ i386 ] < 2.30.0-0ubuntu1.1 -> 3.4.0-0ubuntu1 > ( gnome ) (< 3.2)
Broken gnome-power-manager:i386 Depends on gnome-settings-daemon [ i386 ] < 2.30.1-0ubuntu1.1 -> 3.4.1-0ubuntu1 > ( gnome ) (>= 3.2)
Broken gnome-icon-theme-symbolic:i386 Breaks on gnome-power-manager [ i386 ] < 2.30.0-0ubuntu1.1 -> 3.4.0-0ubuntu1 > ( gnome ) (< 3.2)
Broken gnome-power-manager:i386 Depends on gnome-settings-daemon [ i386 ] < 2.30.1-0ubuntu1.1 -> 3.4.1-0ubuntu1 > ( gnome ) (>= 3.2)
Broken gnome-icon-theme-symbolic:i386 Breaks on gnome-power-manager [ i386 ] < 2.30.0-0ubuntu1.1 -> 3.4.0-0ubuntu1 > ( gnome ) (< 3.2)
Broken gnome-power-manager:i386 Depends on gnome-settings-daemon [ i386 ] < 2.30.1-0ubuntu1.1 -> 3.4.1-0ubuntu1 > ( gnome ) (>= 3.2)
Broken gnome-icon-theme-symbolic:i386 Breaks on gnome-power-manager [ i386 ] < 2.30.0-0ubuntu1.1 -> 3.4.0-0ubuntu1 > ( gnome ) (< 3.2)
Broken gnome-power-manager:i386 Depends on gnome-settings-daemon [ i386 ] < 2.30.1-0ubuntu1.1 -> 3.4.1-0ubuntu1 > ( gnome ) (>= 3.2)
Broken gnome-icon-theme-symbolic:i386 Breaks on gnome-power-manager [ i386 ] < 2.30.0-0ubuntu1.1 -> 3.4.0-0ubuntu1 > ( gnome ) (< 3.2)
Broken gnome-power-manager:i386 Depends on gnome-settings-daemon [ i386 ] < 2.30.1-0ubuntu1.1 -> 3.4.1-0ubuntu1 > ( gnome ) (>= 3.2)
```

Do I have to uninstall all these broken packages? Are there any other way to update Ubuntu without losing my data?

Thanks in advance !! :)

Comment: It is going to be faster and more reliable to do a fresh install

Comment: Finally I did that hehe.

Answer (score 0):

I did a fresh install because it was really hard to update it.